# Intellij IDEA HELP Console Application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console

I just started programmin on Java using IDE Intellij IDEA and I really need some help with it. 
Here is the question: how to create console application? I tryed to google it but the only thing I found was how to create just an application, not a console. 
I need to read strings from keyboard and when I use System.console().readLine() it throws an exception: NullPointerException because it need console but not a little window under the code in IDE.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.in` as console:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scanner.next();
```

In IntelliJ IDEA you can enter values in bottom console as if you were in real console.